# Python Selenium .click() not working after using ActionChains

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making a search on Youtube, then I press a few TAB, then I press a few END via the ActionChains... Then I want to grab the results and if I find what I want, I want to click on it.

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
time.sleep(4)
items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search']")
rand = random.choice(query)
items.send_keys(rand)
items.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)

action = ActionChains(driver)

for i in range(5):
    action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(1)


for i in range(3):
    action.send_keys(Keys.END)
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(4)

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='primary']//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]")

for i in items:
    if ......... :
        i.click()
```

Usually, after using:   `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH....`    I can do a

```
for i in items:
    if ...... :
    i.click()
```

But now it's not working since I've been using the `action = ActionChains(driver)`

I'm getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer, the problem is youtube and not selenium.  i.click() works, the problem was my find_elements(By.XPATH, ... youtube also has invisible elements form the home page that are included in the result page, which gave me invisible items.

once I changed my XPATH to:

```
//ytd-search[@class='style-scope ytd-page-manager']//div[@id='primary']//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]")
```

it worked